# SD Card voids writes

Tags: linux, partitioning, sd-card, format, filesystem-corruption

I have a 2 GB SD card that I plug into my computer through a switchless USB adapter. At first, the SD card was unformatted, so I gave it a msdos partition table and a total FAT32 partition.

I use the SD card in a quadcopter which stores pictures and video in it, and when I opened it again in my computer, I could see the files but there was an input/output error in the card. So I proceed to format it again, after all else fails, and then I am unable to do so. (I don't remember any specific error for this specific action).

Then I try `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb` on it, to see if it would format now. I try to format it again (using **GParted** in Linux) and before writing to the card I see that the SD Card is all empty, without a partition table. I try to create a msdos partition table, but the SD Card seems to not accept the writes from GParted. Each time I scan it, GParted reads an empty block.

I try to read the card's partitions with **fdisk** and **parted**, and both read successfully the msdos partition table; fdisk detects a partition with a FAT32 filesystem with the correct size, parted only detects the size of the partition.

From this point onwards, every attempt to write anything to the SD card fails. No errors are reported, but each time I read the SD card with either fdisk or parted, the results are the same.

I have tried commands such as

- `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1`
- `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=1`
- `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb`
- `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb1`
- `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb`
- `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb1`

and still nothing changes. This short test verifies that the card is voiding the writes, I recon:

```
> $ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/tmp/sdout0 bs=512 count=1                                                                             
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes (512 B) copied, 0,00201869 s, 254 kB/s

> $ sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1                                                                            
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes (512 B) copied, 0,0119276 s, 42,9 kB/s

> $ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/tmp/sdout1 bs=512 count=1                                                                             
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes (512 B) copied, 0,00187789 s, 273 kB/s

> $ diff -s /tmp/sdout0 /tmp/sdout1
Files /tmp/sdout0 and /tmp/sdout1 are identical
```

All I get from `dmesg` is

```
[  733.852106] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[  733.985255] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=aaaa, idProduct=8816
[  733.985267] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  733.985275] usb 2-3: Product: MXT USB Device
[  733.985282] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: MXTronics
[  733.985288] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 130818v01
[  733.986147] usb-storage 2-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  733.986663] scsi9 : usb-storage 2-3:1.0
[  734.984738] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     MXT-USB  Storage Device   1308 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  734.985124] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  734.991101] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] 3934208 512-byte logical blocks: (2.01 GB/1.87 GiB)
[  734.991829] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  734.991839] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  734.992438] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  734.992443] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  734.997992]  sdb: sdb1
[  735.000956] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

This card is new. The only writes done to it where the ones I mentioned here, so I find it hard to believe the card is damaged. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: It's either a faulty card or a faulty write-protect switch, which amounts to the same thing. Get a replacement: they cost next to nothing. If the problem persists then you have a faulty USB reader.

Comment: If its new, even better, its under warranty, and they'll need to replace it for you

Comment: Well the reader I believe is just a "passive" adapter, and it has no switches, so I guess this leads to my SD card being faulty. Is it true some SD cards have an internal software failure protection mechanism?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yeah, but I bought it on another country and dealing with the shop is not an option for me, so my best bet if the card is faulty is buying a new one.